# how to accessing vectors in a loop

Tags: c++, object, vector

I am programming a Space Invaders clone and I am struggling at creating the bullets.
 Whenever I click Space a bullet is supposed to be added to the vector and then I want to move them via a loop, but I dont understand how to create and handle it the proper way.

```
vector<Bullet> bullets(MAXBULLETS);
int bulletcounter = 0;
while (1) {
    Sleep(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(bullets)-1; i++) {
        bullets[i].Move(0, 1);
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)) {
        Bullet *bullet = new Bullet();
        bullets[bulletcounter] = bullet;  // Here is the error
        bulletcounter++;
    }
```

Comment: "Here is the error" does not tell us **what** the error is. And the verb "to handle" is too vague. It could mean anything.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: bullets is a vector of Bullet not Bulleet*  and bullets[bulletcounter] = bullet; yor are assigning it a pointer.

Comment: Does your code compile or not ?

Comment: As @user1438832 said.  Solution is to create `bullets` empty, and then `bullets.push_back(Bullet());` or `bullets.emplace_back()`.

Comment: in addition to user1438832, it's not recommended to use `new` in this way. It can cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bullets` is a vector that holds objects of type `Bullet`.

```
Bullet *bullet = new Bullet();
bullets[bulletcounter] = bullet;  // Here is the error
```

Your `bullet` here is of type `Bullet*`. The two incompatible types get you the error.

---

To fix this, stop using a pointer and just instantiate an object:

```
Bullet bullet;
```

This creates a `Bullet` object using the parameterless constructor that you can then add to your `bullets`.

Do note though, that this currently does nothing since you initialize your vector giving it a predefined size `bullets(MAXBULLETS)`, this already creates `MAXBULLETS` default constructed objects for you, ready to use:

> Constructs the container with count default-inserted instances of T.
>   No copies are made.

---

Side note : stop using `new` altogether; this isn't Java or C#. If you need a dynamically allocated object then use a smart pointer. Most of the time, though, an object automatic-storage duration will do just fine.

Comment: As I am not a native speaker, what was wrong with the "however"?

Answer (score 0):

My proposal

```
vector<Bullet> bullets;

while (1)
{
    Sleep(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++)
    {
         bullets[i].Move(0, 1);
    }

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
    {
       bullets.push_back(Bullet());            
    }
```